# How to do this hibernate mapping?

Tags: hibernate, orm, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I am newbie to hibernate world, so sort of confused in writing mapping file in following condition.

I have following class which I want to persist using hibernate :

```
class Project {
    int projectID;
    List<String> clients;
    List<String> employers;

    List<String> technologies;
    String description;
}
```

I have already created following tables manually in database :

```
+---------------------------+
           project
+---------------------------+

 project_id (pk) | description
+---------------------------+
```

---

```
+---------------------------+    
          organizations
+---------------------------+
  org_id(pk)      | org_name
+---------------------------+
```

to link `organization` and `project` table, I have following tables:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
                      project_clients
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
  project_id(fk of projects)  | client_id(fk of organizations)
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
                     project_employers
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
  project_id(fk of projects) | employer_id(fk of organizations)
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have no clue about how to map these tables to my `project` class? Any idea how it is done?

I tried to take advantage of lists but with lists persistence we cannot use link table like (`project_clients` or `project_employers`) and I don't want to create separate class for client list and employer list. Or is it the only option?

Please help !

---

EDIT 1
Thanks guys for answers. I have one more query. How to tell hibernate that for client (for example 'foo company') it should search 'foo company' in organizations table and if that name is present then take its corresponding ID and put it in project_clients table. If 'foo company' is not present in 'organizations' table then add it and then take its corresponding ID. I want to do the same thing for employer also. Is it possible to do this thing in hibernate?

Currently I have written program in java to do all this.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a straightforward way to achieve what you want:

```
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int projectID;
    @ElementCollection
    List<String> clients;
    @ElementCollection
    List<String> employers;
    @ElementCollection
    List<String> technologies;
    String description;
}
```

**Note that @CollectionsOfElements is deprecated, so you better use @ElementCollection**

Let me know if it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

I think following mapping will solve your problem

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name="project")
  class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int projectID;
    String description;
    //for joing the tables (many-to-many)
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_clients",
    joinColumns = {
               @JoinColumn(name="projectId") 
             },
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="clientId")})

    private Set<Organization> clients;

   public Set<Organization> getClients(){ 
        return clients; 
   }
   public void setClients(Set<Organization> clients){ 
        this.clients= clients; 
   }

   //same for employers

   @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinTable(name = "project_employers",
   joinColumns = {
               @JoinColumn(name="projectId") 
             },
   inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="employerId")})

   private Set<Organization> employers;

   public Set<Organization> getEmployers(){ 
        return employers; 
   }
   public void setEmployers(Set<Organization> employers){ 
        this.employers= employers; 
   }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have one query. How to tell hibernate that for client (for example 'foo company') it should search 'foo company' in organizations table and if that name is present then take its corresponding ID and put it in project_clients table. If 'foo company' is not present in 'organizations' table then add it and then take its corresponding ID. I want to do the same thing for employer also. Is it possible to do this thing in hibernate?